# How to split a column into two in Bash shell

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a huge file with many column. I want to count the number of occurences of each values in 1 column. Therefore, I use
`cut -f 2 "file" | sort | uniq -c` 
. I got the result as I want. However, when I read this file to R, It shows that I have only 1 column but the data is like the example below
Example:

```
123 Chelsea
65 Liverpool
77 Manchester city
2 Brentford
```

The thing I want is two columns, one for the counts the other for the names. However, I got one only. Can anyone help me to split the column into 2 or a better method to extract from the big file?

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: What you ask for is not clear. In the example you show there is not one column, there are at least 2: `124` and `Chelsea` in the first line, for instance.

Comment: Hi, when I read it into R or when I write "cut -f 1 "file" ", there is only one column. I mean when "cut -f 1", I get 124 Chelsea, not 124.

Comment: The default `cut` delimiter is TAB, not space. Try `cut -d ' ' -f 1` and see. If you want the separator between the first field (count) and the rest to be a TAB you must post-process the `uniq -c` output with, e.g., `sed`: `sort | uniq -c | sed 's/ /\t/'`. Please edit your question to add that you want a TAB as column separator, not a space.

Comment: Define what you mean by "column". If we understand that a white space is a column separator, you already have two columns.

Comment: Note that when you use `cut`, you can define a column separator. By default, it is a tab.

Comment: I've used `cat infile | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | awk '{print $1","$2}'` before to manage the whitespace a little better.  The `cut` becomes a little easier after that.  If I needed more than that, I'd move to `perl`.  (I only know enough `awk` to be dangerous.)

Comment: Hi, I just edit the question so that it is cleared, I think people are misunderstand me :")

Comment: No, it's not clearer. Please add the important missing information: you want a TAB between the count and the rest while `uniq -c` puts a space. And read again my previous comment it shows a solution.

Comment: I think I get you, Its working @RenaudPacalet, but Ive never learned sed before, can you explain to me what does sed 's/ /\t/'  do?

Comment: `sed` has a substitute command: `s/pattern/replacement/` that replaces the first encountered `pattern` by `replacement` on each line of the input. Here the `pattern` is a space and the replacement is a tab (`\t`).

Comment: **Please edit your question**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply count the unique instances in each column, your best bet would be the `cut` command with the custom delimiter. For instance, it would be the whitespace delimiter.

In this case you have to consider that you have subsequent spaces after the first one e.g. `Manchester city`.

So, in order to count the unique occurrences of the first column:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 <your_file> | uniq | wc -l
```

where `-d` sets the delimiter to whitespace `' '`, and `-f1` gives you the first column; `uniq` keeps the unique instances and `wc -l` counts the number of occurrences.

Similarly, to count the unique occurrences of the second column:

```
cut -d ' ' -f2- <your_file> | uniq | wc -l
```

where all parameters/commands are the same except for `-f2-` which allows you to get the from the second column to the last (see `cut` [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) `-f<from>-<to>`).

**EDIT**

Based on the update of your question, here is a proposition on how to get what you want in **r**:

You can use `cut` with `pipe`:

```
df = read.csv(pipe("cut -f1,2- -d ' ' <your_csv_file>"))
```

And this should return a dataframe with the data separated as you want.

Comment: No need for the cat though. `cut ... <your_file> | ...`

Comment: I just edit the question can you read that again?

Comment: @JVevermind I haven't worked with `r` in a long time, but probably you want to put some delimiter in the file that `r` is able to understand as a column separator by default. I would try with comma `,` and semicolon `;`.

Comment: @JVevermind check out the edit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not a beautiful solution, but try this.
Pipe the output of the previous command into this while loop:

```
"your program" | while read count city
 do
 printf "%20s\t%s" $count $city
 done
```